# Silverlight rich text editor that knows to export rich text to html?

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, export, rich-text-editor

I'm creating a Silverlight app. 
One of the functionality the client wishes is to have a rich text editor that provides simple formatting capabilities such as: *blod, italic, color* (no paragraphs or padding or alignments or the like). This rich text editor should be able to export it's content to html in-memory. Why? Because the html will ultimatley be part of a dynamic form that get's serialized in a custom xml format and ultimateley will be sent to an ipad that knows how to de-serialize it and render it. (html will be read-only on ipad, not editable)

First question: Do you know any free/commercial library you know provides me with a rich text editor with such a feature? (would prefer it does not use a server side html generator, but if there's not alternative it's ok that way too). 
I did already have a look at telerik, so besides that.

Second question: Do you see any big problems I may encounter with this approach of serializing html on the server side, and displaying it on an ipad, as part of a larger data entry form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Nevron.

A full featured text editor for Silverlight comes with NOV. It supports import/export to/from RTF and HTML with great accuracy. It can export to PDF too. It is not free, but it is really the best you will find for Silverlight. See it action here:

http://www.nevron.com/Support.OnlineLiveDemos.aspx

Answer (score 1):

VectorLight has a Free  Richtextbox that exports to HTML.

http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight.aspx